# Restrict dropbox syncing by time

Tags: dropbox

Now I have unlim Internet only on some part of day(`03:00` - `08:00`).

Is it possible to allow DropBox syncing only in this time and pause syncing at other time?

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [official Dropbox CLI](http://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) to start/stop the dropboxd by cron.

Unfortunately there is no support to pause syncing.

You can also install dropboxd as a system daemon using this [how to](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/TextBasedLinuxInstall#Runningonsystemstartup).

Answer (score 1):

You can just end the dropbox process then, and restart it later. That should do what you want.

Syntax for the scheduled task is: `Taskkill /IM dropbox.exe`

Comment: hm, ok probably I can use `cron`. Can I do not start/stop but only pause/resume syncing by command line?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what firewall you use, you may be able to set up a rule to block traffic from the DropBox app during certain times of the day, and allow it at other times of the day.

Comment: Is there a reliable way to block packets per-process in Linux? I think packet matching by pid was deprecated in iptables sometime ago. Of course, it's possible to run dropbox as distinct user and match packets by --uid-owner

Comment: I don't know.  I answered before question was edited.  Personally, I try to stay away from iptables whenever possible simply because I don't feel comfortable configuring it properly.